# How to have emacs count an increment of words?

Tags: emacs, version-control, input, word-count

Implementing the [Martini method](http://www.academicproductivity.com/2008/how-to-complete-your-phd-or-any-large-project-hard-and-soft-deadlines-and-the-martini-method/), I'd like to count the number of words added to a file since last checkpoint (say, each day).

I guess I could count the words of an older backed-up version, count the words in the current version, and difference, but it sounds like much processing is useless, and there are files to manage in the way.

Is there a way to count this on the way, that is, **have a progressive count that takes all input into account, and that I would be able to reset at any point ?**

I don't mind it dying between sessions. I see yanking as a possible issue, but mostly I have no idea about how to process the input rather than file diffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what I came up with, following [terdon's ideas](https://superuser.com/a/513661/162290).

I'm pretty happy with it, it does what I wanted, over a few files in the `my-martini-files` variable.

<sup><sub>Edit :</sub></sup> A temporary count has been added, which allows to stack progress, and still reset the count sometimes, not to take heavy copy/paste that shouldn't add words into account for the progress achieved.

I bound it to <kbd>f4</kbd> for a report, <kbd>C-f4</kbd> to re-initialize the count (of files), <kbd>S-f4</kbd> to stack progress, and <kbd>C-S-f4</kbd> to start a new day, all counts at 0.

Fanciness would now consist in integrating it to the modeline, but that's another matter.

```
;; Teh Martini method
(require 'wc) ; The file terdon links to.
(defun wc-in-buffer (file)
  "Return the number of words in the buffer opening the file
passed as an argument. It should already be open."
  (with-current-buffer (get-file-buffer file)
    (wc-non-interactive (point-min) (point-max)))
  )
(defun my-martini-sum ()
  "Sum words over my-martini-files."
  (apply '+ 
     (loop for file in my-martini-files
        collect (wc-in-buffer file)))
  )
(setq my-martini-files '("~/path/to/file.org"
                         "~/path/to/another/file.org"
                         ;; Taken from org-agenda-files
             ))
```

(defun my-martini-update () 
  "Update my-martini-count from files."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-martini-count (my-martini-sum))
  (message "Files lengths updated."))
(defun my-martini-reset ()
  "Reset counts and stack for a new day."
  (interactive)
  (my-martini-update)
  (setq my-martini-stack 0)
  (message "Martini counts re-initialized."))
(defun my-martini-stack () 
  "Stack the current progress, and update. 
To be used before pasting loads of unsignificant words."
  (interactive)
  (setq my-martini-stack (+ my-martini-stack (- (my-martini-sum) my-martini-count)))
  (message "Current count is stacked. Mess at will, just update afterwards.")
  )
(defun my-martini-report ()
  "Display changes in total word count since last update."
  (interactive)
  (message (concat "As for now, "
           (number-to-string (+ my-martini-stack (- (my-martini-sum) my-martini-count)))
           " new words have been added today."))
  )
(global-set-key [f4] 'my-martini-report)
(global-set-key [\C-f4] 'my-martini-update)
(global-set-key [\S-f4] 'my-martini-stack)
(global-set-key [\C-\S-f4] 'my-martini-reset)

Any comments or suggestions to improve the code are dearly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call a word count function the first time you open an emacs session and save the result into a variable. Then, you can run the word count command again and process the result to get the number of words added.

I gave this a go but my emacs-lisp foo is pitiful. If you are more knowledgeable of and comfortable with emacs-lisp than I, you should be able to edit [this word count function](http://pastebin.com/tUYaZSWh) to suit your needs. Please post back here if you do, I'd like to see how :).

I got the function and some other useful information from the [emacs wiki word count page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WordCount).

---

If an emacs-less solution is acceptable, you could try adding these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function start_count(){
  wc -w $1 | cut -f 1 -d" " > ~/.count; 
  emacs $1
}
function show_progress(){
    p=`cat ~/.count`; 
    c=`wc -w $1  | cut -f 1 -d" "`; 
    echo "You have written "$(($c-$p))" words today!"
}
```

Now, when you start working, you open your file for editing and save its current word count into `~/.count` like so:

```
start_count file.txt
```

When you want to check your progress just run :

```
show_progress file.txt
```

Bear in mind that this will treat LaTeX control sequences as words, so the count might not be perfect. Don't know how to get around that though...

Comment: I'll read into more detail tonight, but that'll go with free text in org-mode, LaTeX sequences won't be an issue for now. Moreover, once the “update” part is managed, I guess it should be easy to replace `wc` by some `count-true-words-lost-in-markup` function for any markup language, for which I saw a few answers already existed.

Comment: Ok so *tonight* became yet another *asap*, but here's the update :·) Thanks a lot for your ideas. Oh, and my elisp got a lot better tonight  thanks to that =)